# Layout distorted when viewed on mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, codeigniter

I am developing a web site on my localhost. I used the following technologies:

CodeIgniter in my backend, Bootstrap and JQuery on front.

The problem is, when I viewed my site on my phone when accessing my localhost, it got distorted , css does not load correctly, and it seems that javascripts doesn't work. I can't even login.

Why is that so?

Below is the print screen when viewed on mobile.

[image]

I am confused where the things got wrong. But I suspect, it is on codeigniter.

Your replies will be appreciated!

Comment: Chances are your `base_url` in your config file is set to something like `'http://localhost/ssmis/'`, yet you're trying to access the site on `192.168.43.159/ssmis`, which is clearly **not** the same as `'http://localhost/ssmis/'`. Try changing your `base_url` to `192.168.43.159/ssmis/`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct! You saved the day! Thanks!

Comment: No worries at all, I've added this as an answer with a bit more explanation to aid other users who might be searching for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely scenario is that the `base_url` in your config file is set to something like `'http://localhost/ssmis/'`.

This is fine for local development, as you're accessing the site on `localhost`. However, `localhost` won't work on other machines in your network, so as you noticed you have to enter in the IP address of your computer to test the app. This causes an issue because all your internal URLs in your app still point to `localhost`, which your mobile device can't access, so assets and URLs (basically, your entire app) won't work.

The solution is to update your `base_url` to your IP. For example, you can try changing it to `192.168.43.159/ssmis/` for testing. Don't forget to change it back when you want to work on your local machine again.